# Plot csv file series using python

Tags: python, plot

What is a very efficient way I can read data from a csv file then produce a graph of the different columns, where each column is graphed as a different color? I am interested in a method that can be generalized for several columns. The method I tried took far too much time to run. I tried pandas.DataFrame.from_csv with matplotlib.pyplot, but my implementation may have been incorrect. I would like to see a simple example of a high efficiency csv graphing program.

```
x,2x,x^2,x^3
1,2,1,1
2,4,4,8
3,6,9,27
4,8,16,64
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) useful if you have not looked into it already.

(I'd add this as a comment rather than a response but don't have enough reputation yet to comment)

Comment: I tried pandas.DataFrame.from_csv with matplotlib.pyplot, but my implementation may have been incorrect. I would like to see a simple example of a high efficiency csv graphing program.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem:

```
from pandas import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pandas.DataFrame.from_csv('dat.dat')
plt.figure(); df.plot(); plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.legend(loc=5,prop={'size':6})
plt.show()
```

Comment: technically, you don't need `padnas`, but it sure makes code shorter!